# how do I format currency inside the expression of Excel cell?

Tags: excel, formatting, expression, worksheet-function

I am trying to figure out how to format the result in an expression in Excel. I wrote

```
=IF(C30 > B30, "You would save $" & Format(C30-B30, "Currency") & "!", "No savings")
```

inside the cell but it doesn't work. Simply put, I want the currency formatted inside the expression.

How?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried the [Text](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) function?

```
=IF(C30 > B30, "You would save " & Text(C30-B30, "$0.00") & "!", "No savings")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula

```
=IF(C30 > B30, "You would save " & Currency(C30-B30, 0) & "!", "No savings")
```

Answer (score 2):

Many years later, this works, too!

```
=IF(C4>D4,"You would save " & DOLLAR(C4-D4,2) & "!","No Savings!")
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for the Concatenate function. Excel doesn't seem to have the Format function you have indicated.

This worked for me in Excel 2007:

```
=IF(C30 > B30, CONCATENATE("You would save $",C30-B30, "!"), "No savings")
```

Comment: Yes, I like Anders's Text function better, as well.